# Where should the cache file be stored at?

Tags: php, caching

I was thinking of cache for my php project, a mini shopping cart that interacts with the database, but am not sure where the cache file is stored, on the server or on the client's system plus how to best use cache in php?.

Comment: You can use APC - Alternative PHP Cache on server.

Comment: You have to give much more details. Otherwise it is impossible to answer to this question. _What_ do you want to cache? _Why_ do you want to cache? _How_ should the cache behave? _Which_ goal to you want to achieve by caching? So please edit your question by using the `edit` button above and add more details. please do _not_ add details by posting comments yourself.